# Delphi. Using try/except throughout the code. Evil?

Tags: delphi, exception

This is rather theoretical question.

I've encountered this practice in a recent project - almost every procedure and function is wrapped into try/except clause like so:

```
function TMyClass.DoFoo(aBar: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  try
    .. do something .. // Proper checks for common errors inside
    Result := True;
  except
    LogException(ClassName + '.DoFoo'); // Write exception to log
    Result := False; // Indicate function did not performed what it was asked for
    // Exit without re-raising exception
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.Buzz(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    .. do something .. // Proper checks for common errors inside
  except
    LogException(ClassName + '.DoFoo'); // Write exception to log
    // Exit without re-raising exception
  end;
end;
```

This looks like a lot of repetition. However I can see some kind of logic behind it. If you wrap every procedure and function into `try..except` you would know approximate location of the exception and let the program continue working without popping crash messages at the user, but write them to a log for future analysis.

However this practice is considered to be evil. Why exactly is that?

EDIT:

- This is a question about project I'm going to work with, I did not invented it myself
- I'm well aware about madExcept and I use it in other projects
- Functions and procedures in that project are layed out as usual, there are no signs of procedures being written as functions for sole purpose of *replacing* exceptions flow

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Delphi handles exceptions, but in other languages (e.g. Java) it's typically more expensive in terms of performance to use `try ... catch` rather than using `if`-statements. Also, wrapping entire function bodies in `try ... except` like that makes it seem like the developer hasn't spent any time thinking about what could go wrong, and instead just said "let's catch every erroneous situation and handle all of them the same way".

Comment: @Michael: That is two points - **slower code** and **defensive coding**. There are errors handling inside the function of course too.

Comment: Not sure if I would call that _defensive_ coding (defensive coding is generally a good thing). I would call it _paranoid_ or _clueless_ coding instead.

Comment: @Rudy: This is not that clueless though - there's all kinds of checks inside these functions/procedures.

Comment: @Krom Isn't the point that you are forcing yourself to do lots and lots of extra work needlessly. That very fact that these functions are compelled to test return values of every function all is a huge problem.

Comment: @David: I believe you have a wrong assumption that every procedure in that project was converted to a function - that is not so. So far exploring the project I found that functions and procedures are layed out as normal. It's just that each one is wrapped into these try/except clause.

Comment: So how do these procedures indicate error?

Comment: Recently I've started to work on a project which does the same as you've shown in your example. Result ? I'm rewriting it from scratch. The program flow there is totally broken. The author probably thought it is useful to return boolean value (logging all eaten exceptions), but he forgot that the callers need to distinguish e.g. between a negative answer from a successful RPC call and any sort of connection problem. But of course it depends on situation; occasionally you may want to eat all exceptions and return just the state, but in most cases you don't. At least such design is suspicious.

Comment: @David: Apparently they just log it, failing silently without showing to the user.

Comment: @Krom They are not failing. They then continue with normal execution. Since the function failed, any subsequent one that relies on the first will also fail. Thus flooding the log. This code sucks on many levels. Why do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: What I cannot understand is why you think it appropriate to remove error checking, which is what this code does. If you suppress exceptions then there needs to be an alternative error handling mechanism. You seem to be saying that exceptions are suppressed and no alternative mechanism is implemented to handle exceptions.

Comment: @David: Please don't put words in my mouth and don't make it personal. I did not said "it's a good idea" nor "it appropriate to remove error checking". I already said that this is not my code and not my decision to keep it like so. There are error checks in appropriate places as far as I have looked. It is just that exceptions are suppressed and logged. I put this question on SO to get solid basis explaining **why exactly it is evil**. Yet judging from answers it seems there are few solid facts and some prejudice.

Comment: I'm not making it personal. I'm talking about the code. I don't see any prejudice. If exceptions are suppressed then there has to be another mechanism. Don't you agree. DoFoo returns a boolean. Every caller has to check the return value of DoFoo. And then pass it on to its caller. And so on. If not then the program will continue with normal execution flow in spite of pre-conditions not having been met. Or is the intention to log errors but ignore them and hope that they don't matter? That's what Buzz seems to do.

Comment: As for putting words into your mouth, it seems that you think the code is fine as it is. Your comments seem to indicate that. I'm trying to get a handle on why you think that it's alright to suppress exceptional control flow.

Comment: DoFoo is a function anyway, with try/except or without. Each caller verifies its result (True/False), that how you do foo - you want to verify it succeeded. I see your point when it comes to functions that don't fail (e.g. `StrToInt`). Then try/except would be just as you explain.

Comment: I don't think the code is fine, but I could not point at all of its exact flaws either, so I ask here.

Comment: Your approach is GOOD when the DoFoo MUST NOT fail (raise an error) while this is quite possible to happen. Think at 'unstable' storage medias (external disks, USB disks, network, internet, CD, etc). Otherwise, I would let the program raise the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are all sorts of reasons why this is a simply dreadful idea.

The exception handling is now driving the design of all your functions. They all now need to return booleans. Any real return values have to pass through out parameters. That will destroy the readability of your code and composability of your functions.

And you now need to check the return value of every function call you make and propagate that exception upwards. You've therefore abandoned all the benefits of exception handling. The great thing about exceptions is that you can largely separate normal flow from exceptional flow. With your proposed change, exceptional flow in front and centre.

The other big problem is that you force the code to handle the error as early as possible. But the code at the point where the exception is raised might not be in a position to handle the error. If you let the error float upwards then the code can handle the error at the point where it is able to do so.

If you want the program to log details of an error, and not show a message to the user, that is easy to achieve with exception handling. You can use tools like madExcept, EurekaLog or JclDebug to help make the logging comprehensive.

Comment: #1: Good point. #2: Not necessarily, it looks like crashed functions are just proclaimed to be equivalent to failed. #3: if inner function failed for *whatever* reason it's parents functions to handle that anyway

Comment: #2 Yes necessarily. If functions fail, and don't raise, then you must not plug on regardless. #3 Somebody has to deal with it. But not necessarily the immediate caller. Your approach leads to error handling code in every single function. Yes, every single one.

Comment: I hate to agree with Mr Heffernan, but in this case I do.

Answer (score -2):

Your example creates more complex code and in any case, you are much better using a well-respected add-on tool such as [Madexcept](http://madshi.net/) which not only catches any exception but creates - and logs - a wonderful stack trace allowing you to find the point at which the error occurred, even later when a customer complains! The tool has been around for many years now and can also be configured to email you the exception log and/or auto-restart the app. I believe that there is also a tool in the open-source JEDI library that can also create a stack trace in a similar way.

Comment: This is not a suggestion and I'm well aware of madExcept (will add that to question). The question is "However this practice is considered to be evil. Why exactly is that?"

Comment: "Your suggestion creates more complex code", I think that is an important fact, don't you? Also, exception handling hinders performance in general (there is overhead in creating, tracking, and cleaning up frame-based exception handlers - vectored exception handlers are more efficient but less commonly used). It also puts more burden on you to know which code can and cannot raise exceptions in the first place.

Comment: At the very least, you should eliminate the `try/except` blocks where possible and use the `TApplication.OnException` event to log uncaught exceptions, if not using MadExcept or other similar product.

Comment: I was simply trying to be helpful. If you were aware of madExcept then you should have included that statement when you wrote the post, not appended it after I responded.