# IOUtils - Programming approach

Tags: delphi

In IOUtils.pas, Embarcadero, raises exceptions when a problem appears. For example IOUtils.TDirectory.CreateDirectory is a procedure instead of a function that returns true for success / false for failure to create the folder. In Embarcadero's code, CreateDirectory just raises an error. It is true, THEY WARN YOU about it "Note:  SetCurrentDirectory raises an exception if the given path is either invalid or cannot be set as current. "

I can't use any of the functions in IOUtils.pas because I have programs that must continue running even if I have a minor IO problem.

For example:
My program needs to process some data in a folder and put the result back there (and errors can appear quite often because of accidental wrong permissions on that folder). The program has a lot of processing to do so **it would be unreasonable for its user to let it work over night and find it in the morning stuck at 0.2%** because of a "You don't have write permissions to the x folder" message. (A log will show the failed operation)

Other application is a console app. Again, it needs to move on in case of an error. A simple writeln would be sufficient to display the message.
I have my full blown library that does what IOUtils does but (when possible) without raising errors.

Just think at it as a GUI-less application or an application that runs unsupervised so nobody would care what is the reason for which it failed (one possible example would be a Service).

So, is my design wrong? Why did Embarcadero choose to raise errors instead of using Boolean returning functions?  Show I switch to IOUtils and put all its procedures in a try/except?

---

Update
This is how Embarcadero proposes to use their unit:

```
procedure TForm1.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var IsRecursive: Boolean;
begin
  try
    ...
    TDirectory.Delete(edSourcePath.Text, IsRecursive);
  except
    { Catch the possible exceptions }
    MessageDlg('Incorrect path', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Isn't this wrong? How are they sure that the path was invalid? What if the path was correct but the drive was disconnected, or took fire? Or the folder is locked? Or 273 other possible reasons I could came up with?

---

Update 2:

The library still has old... hm, let's call them... issues. For example TDirectory.Exists still returns true for 'c:\Program Files\  ' (NOTICE the space at the end of the path!).

And GetCreationTime still does not work with some files.

Comment: You may take a look at [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22087551/960757).

Comment: No, that's not said there. But I would answer you by the question - how would one distinguish e.g. between an invalid input path and a creation failure from a boolean result ?

Comment: I see your case, but again, if that would be designed as a function returning boolean, how would you e.g. sanitize an invalid directory path entered by the user ? Not today, but tomorrow, for instance. By catching a `EDirectoryNotFoundException` exception when calling the method you could. From a boolean result hardly.

Comment: How could you distinguish between invalid characters in the directory name from hardware is failing. If your program needs to continue even if an exception occured you need to code that. Especially since you don't want to handle every exception the same. You obviously want to create the directory to put files there. What will you do if the directory is not there? If you want to avoid possible exceptions you should do some sanity checks before hand like checking for invalid characters, permissions or whatever can possibly go wrong and can be avoided

Comment: @TLama - So you say I should consider using IOUtils and embrace every single IO function in try/except?

Comment: @StefanGlienke - In this case, I don't need to know the reason. I don't care because the user is not there to take action! I just know that a folder could not be created and I log this 'error' then I move of to the next set of data. The user can manually process that folder OR fix the problem (for example give proper writing rights) OR just ignore that folder. When the user has so much data to process, 10% failure is acceptable!

Comment: For your `Exists` issue, simply always add a path delimiter to the end before you test with `System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter`.

Comment: @Altar If IOUtils does not fit your needs you are free to use the WinAPI directly because it does not raise exceptions! But the IOUtils is for common use and not only for those that "don't need to know the reason and don't care"! However if they not correctly process the result or last error code when the WinAPI call fails thats wrong. Anyway the code example from the doc is bs.

Comment: The approach of IOUtils is correct -- it is the responsibility of library writers to raise exceptions, and the responsibility of the application developer to handle exceptions.

Comment: @Nick Not all failures should result in an exception. Classic example is TryGetValue on a dictionary.

Comment: Never said all failures should result in an exception.

Comment: @Nick So what did you mean. When working with files, failures are common and exceptions can be a pain in the butt.

Comment: @MarcusAdams-It is easy to add an extra line of code to prevent that bug WHEN YOU KNOW ABOUT ITS EXISTENCE! But not everybody knows that function is flawed. If you listen carefully somebody is banging his had into the wall because his program is not working.